# Collapse other Div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The class .notshow is hidden by default and i want the div with .notshow class to be visible after clicking the Show It text inside .shownow class.
I created a jquery code but its not working.
When i click .shownow div all hidden div with .notshow class go visible.
I only want a single div with .notshow class to be visible .

Example: I want to show single div with class .notshow to be visible and if i click another div the previous div should be hidden.
Its Similar to accordion.

*I searched alot on internet but can't find any solution similar to this.
Thanks for help

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yoxo5kfh/3/

```
<div class="data">

<div class="main">
<div class="title">
<div class="shownow"><h4>Show It</h4></div>
</div>
<div class="notshow">
<ul class="catlist">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="main">
<div class="title">
<div class="shownow"><h4>Show It</h4></div>
</div>
<div class="notshow">
<ul class="catlist">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>


<div class="main">
<div class="title">
<div class="shownow"><h4>Show It</h4></div>
</div>
<div class="notshow">
<ul class="catlist">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please update your script in the js fiddle.

Comment: would you like to change your html

Comment: Updated.  I only created jquery to show it.

Comment: @swapnilnax If its similar to this.

Comment: @Kim check the answer that I have put, I have some suggestion for you also in it if there is anything more please do ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, we have to target which one you want to `show`, we can target it by combining..

1. `$(this)` - the element you click.
2. `.closest` - parent of both the element.
3. if you want some animation to use `.slideDown` insted of `.show()` and `.slideUp` insted of `.hide()`

```js
$('body').on('click', '.shownow', function() {
  $('.notshow').removeClass('nohide');
  $(this).closest('.main').find('.notshow').addClass('nohide').toggle();
  $('.notshow').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('nohide')){
       $(this).hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.notshow {
  display: none;
}

.catlist {
  list-style: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">

  <div class="main">
    <div class="title">
      <div class="shownow">
        <h4>Show It</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="notshow">
      <ul class="catlist">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="title">
      <div class="shownow">
        <h4>Show It</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="notshow">
      <ul class="catlist">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="main">
    <div class="title">
      <div class="shownow">
        <h4>Show It</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="notshow">
      <ul class="catlist">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, But what if i want to hide last open div on click Show it.

Comment: When i click the first Show It, It display the .notshow div correctly.But when i click 1 Show It again the .notshow div is still visible.I want the div to be .notshow div to be hidden when clicked again. Thanks for help

Comment: Its working but the problem is now its not hiding other visible div.

Comment: @Kim so you want to hide other div as well as toggle the current div.?? pls ask q specifically clearing the point now own.

Comment: @Kim I have updated the code for you, It will work fine for you if it works don't forget to mark as solved.

Answer (score 0):

try the code below. It will remove the class from all `notshow` and show the closest `notshow` to the clicked element

[Updated fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/yoxo5kfh/4/)

```
$('.shownow').click(function() {
   $(".notshow").removeClass("show")
   $(this).parent().next(".notshow").addClass("show");
})
```

Comment: Thanks, But what if i want to hide last open div on click Show it.

Comment: When i click the first Show It, It display the .notshow div correctly.But when i click 1 Show It again the .notshow div is still visible.I want the div to be .notshow div to be hidden when clicked again. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

A simple show/hide using JQuery. Try the below code, when you click on 'Show It', it finds the '.notshow' in the current parent container and accordingly hides the other containers:

```js
$('.shownow').click(function() {
  $(this).parents(".main:first").find(".notshow").toggle();
});
```

```css
.notshow {
  display: none;
}

.catlist {
  list-style: none;
}

.shownow h4 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">

  <div class="main">
    <div class="title">
      <div class="shownow">
        <h4>Show It</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="notshow">
      <ul class="catlist">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="title">
      <div class="shownow">
        <h4>Show It</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="notshow">
      <ul class="catlist">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="main">
    <div class="title">
      <div class="shownow">
        <h4>Show It</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="notshow">
      <ul class="catlist">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: When i click the first Show It, It display the .notshow div correctly.But when i click 1 Show It again the .notshow div is still visible.I want the div to be .notshow div to be hidden when clicked again. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I have update my answer, This will help you, just add it to your code.

```
<style type="text/css">
.notshow{
    display: none;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).on('click','.shownow', function(){
    var this_display = $ 
(this).parent().next('.notshow').css('display');
    $('.notshow').css('display','none');
    if(this_display=="block"){
        $(this).parent().next('.notshow').css('display','none');
    }else{
        $(this).parent().next('.notshow').css('display','block');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: When i click the first Show It, It display the .notshow div correctly.But when i click 1 Show It again the .notshow div is still visible.I want the div to be .notshow div to be hidden when clicked again. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

```js
let x = document.querySelectorAll('.main');
let list = document.querySelectorAll('.notshow')

let length = x.length;


for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    x[i].onclick = () => {

        if (list[i].classList.contains('show')) {
            list[i].classList.toggle('show');
        } else {
            for (let x = 0; x < length; x++) {
                list[x].classList.remove('show');
            }
            list[i].classList.toggle('show');  // toggle/add
        }
    }
}



//let x = document.querySelectorAll('.main');
//let list = document.querySelectorAll('.notshow')

//let length = x.length;

//for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
//    x[i].onclick = () => {
//        list[i].classList.toggle('show');  // toggle/add
//    }
//}
```

```css
.notshow{
   display:none;  
}
.catlist{
   list-style:none; 
}
 .show{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="data">

        <div class="main">
            <div class="title">
                <div class="shownow">
                    <h4>Show It</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="notshow">
                <ul class="catlist">
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                    <li>Item 2</li>
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                    <li>Item 4</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main">
            <div class="title">
                <div class="shownow">
                    <h4>Show It</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="notshow">
                <ul class="catlist">
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                    <li>Item 2</li>
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                    <li>Item 4</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="main">
            <div class="title">
                <div class="shownow">
                    <h4>Show It</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="notshow">
                <ul class="catlist">
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                    <li>Item 2</li>
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                    <li>Item 4</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: when i again click the same Show It div which i already opened its not closing.

Answer (score 0):

At last got [somethig](https://jsfiddle.net/yoxo5kfh/13/) will be able for you

```
<div class="data">

<div class="main">
<div class="title">
<div class="shownow"><h4>Show It</h4></div>
</div>
<div class="notshow">
<ul class="catlist">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="main">
<div class="title">
<p class="shownow"><h4>Show It</h4><p>
</div>
<div class="notshow">
<ul class="catlist">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>


<div class="main">
<div class="title">
<div class="shownow"><h4>Show It</h4></div>
</div>
<div class="notshow">
<ul class="catlist">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<p>Hello</p>
<p class="selected">Hello Again</p>
<div><span>And Again</span></div>
<script>
var elms = $( "div.notshow" )
$(document).on("click", ".title", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.notshow').removeClass('show');

    $(this).closest('div').next('.notshow').addClass('show');
}); 

</script>
```

Comment: Are answers have same effect,But when i click Show It it shows the .notshow class but when i again click the same Show It div which i already opened its not closing. All is good with code but it should also close when i click the same Show It div again. Thanks.